# Check Seasonality in time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have 2 years of hourly data.I want to check seasonality .
1.Decomposing the series shows seasonality.But since Decomposition is not enough 
 what else can i use to check seasonality in R?
2.I tried hourly seasonality , I am not sure on the period of seasonality.How to determine the frequency in R?

Answer (score 0):

Frequency    is the number of observations per unit of time. But, in my short experience, the unit of time depends on the event you are studying. For example, if you have monthly data of a yearly seasonal event (like the flowering of some plants) and you sampled 5 times each month, frequency will be 5*12. I suggest you decompose your time series and and check for seasonality there. You can use `ts`, `stl` and `plot.stl`.  Try to adjust the parameters as best as you can but also try to check what happens when you change them.

Comment: I am not able to interpret the seasonal plot .Can you please elaborate on seasonal_plot.

Comment: The seasonal plot takes out the trend and just show you the seasonality of the events. For example, if an event occurs once a year every February, but the value of the event is different every year, the seasonal plot will show you a pick of the same size in all Februaries.  By the other hand, the trend plot will remove the seasonal component and will just show you the differences between the years. Check the help, it will tell you something like...The seasonal component is found by loess smoothing the seasonal sub-series. The seasonal values are removed to find the trend.

Answer (score 0):

Please read through below link, if you feel to keep multiple seasonal periods in data, you can also paste sample of your data here for further suggestions

https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/

Comment: tbats model says no seasonality,decomposition plot says there is seasonality.So i am not sure which direction to proceed

Comment: refer `plot_seasonal()` from `stlplus()` package to know the evolution rate of seasonality from your data and for more please refer https://www.wessa.net/download/stl.pdf